# Remote Backups of my dedicated server

Tags: backup, remote, incremental-backup

I'm hosting with ThePlanet and while I love their services, their backup services are a bit pricey.  To backup my whole server (incrementally) would cost $50/mo on top of my server fee (around $120).  I want to host all of my sites there on the same server for ease of use and to make it more affordable.  The problem I run into is backups.  HostGator offers unlimited disk space and backups.  I'm considering setting up WHM so it does FTP backups to a machine located at my house on a secondary hard drive.

What do you guys think of this?  Are there better backup services out there I'm unaware of, or is this my most affordable option?

Incremental backup options would be preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I sell online backup services.

Backing up to your home server is going to be slow unless you have a particularly good internet connection, and even then it's not going to be great.  Your home is not going to be particularly good for protecting the machine against fire or theft.  You'd also want to have a static IP if you're pushing to your home server.

There are some very good online backup services which are quite affordable, especially if you go for an unmanaged one.  Rsync.net are great for options, Amazon S3 or RackSpace Cloud Files are both good on price, and there are other options too.  Some of these options also provide geo redundancy so you get your data backed up to multiple locations.  Managed services such as the one we provide are quite a lot more expensive, but will add a person testing your backups for you.

When pricing up online backup services, remember how much effort they will save in not having to manage your own server at home and add in the extra bandwidth and power you will be using at home for your own server.

Answer (score 0):

I've used two services for off-site backup needs in the past... I've used [ExaVault](http://www.exavault.com/) for a fixed quarterly cost solution and I've used [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) more recently. In both cases I used [Duplicity](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/) with GNU Privacy Guard (GPG) to perform my backups. Duplicity handles full and incremental backups easily and with GPG encrypts the backups being stored on a third-party solution.